For Xcode 13, what is the file path I need to use the iPhone emulator in Visual Studio on a PC?
I have my Mac on the same network as my PC running Visual Studio and it connected successfully. When I try to start the emulator I get the following error:
Could not find a valid Xcode app bundle at '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'. Please update your Apple SDK location in Visual Studio's preferences

I have also tried:

Macintosh HD/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
Applications/Xcode.app
Downloads/Xcode.app

How do I determine the correct value here?

have you installed Command Line Tools on the Mac?

Please check whether Use default xcode path is checked in Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings -> Apple SDK in VS.
If the error message is still displayed after checking it, you can try to add / at the end of the custom Xcode path: /Applications/Xcode.app/.
In addition, if your Xcode does not have the command line tools installed, you can refer to the solution in the github issue: error in MAUI App.
